# How do I integrate $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+9x+5}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+9x+5}}$?
Please I really need help. Can you provide all the steps and a explanation of them?

Comment: For reference:  *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{1}{64} \left(4 \sqrt{x (2 x+9)+5} (4 x-27)+203 \sqrt{2} \log \left(4 x+2 \sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{x (2 x+9)+5}+9\right)\right)$

Comment: I hope this can help you



http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TrigSubstitutions.aspx

Example 6 looks similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+9x+5}}dx$$
First step is to complete the square on the denominator: $2x^2+9x+5=2(x+\frac{9}{4})^2-\frac{41}{8}$

2nd step is substitution - use $\cosh u=\sqrt\frac{41}{16}(x+\frac{9}{4})$. Then the integral $I$ becomes $$\int \frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{16}{41}}\cosh u-\frac{9}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}\cosh^2u-\frac{41}{8}}}\sqrt\frac{16}{41}\sinh u du$$
$$=\int\frac{\frac{16}{41}\cosh^2u-\frac{18}{\sqrt{41}}\cosh u+\frac{81}{16}}{\frac{41}{8\sqrt2}}du$$
This can be more easily evaluated.

---

Alternatively, if you're unfamiliar with hyperbolic functions, substituting in 
$\sec u=\sqrt\frac{41}{16}(x+\frac{9}{4})$ will likely also work, since the $\tan u$ in $dx=k\sec u \tan u$ will cancel with the one produced on the numerator, and you'll be left integrating powers of $\sec u$.